# Partitioning instead of thousand tables with identical structure

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I have legacy, but pretty big(~25Gb) database questionably designed. The "pattern" which is commonly used across whole database boils down to the following:

- separate logical parts into different tables (journal_1, journal_2, journal_n)
- all tables have a unique bigserial/autoincrement field (journal_id_seq_1, journal_id_seq_2, journal_id_seq_n)
- all tables have one or several foreign keys to one or several reference tables(journal tables have 2 foreign keys, group of tables with another structure(log_1, log_2, log_n) referenced just to one)

I'm extremely curious (actually near to panic :) in what happens if there are about 50 thousand such tables(Now is "just" about 15k).

My idea is get everything together(tables with identical structure) in one huge table with a common name(let's say journal), add a column with a journal_id(extracted from a suffix journal_{1|2|3}) partitioned by this column and obviously create partition tables for each table with same naming convention. Moreover, bigserial fields need to be converted into regular bigints, but I still need keep sequences for each partition and manually call nextval on every insert. Primary key also need to be extended with journal_id field additionally to seq_id.  Finally, I see a bonus in a sharding which can be applied to partitions when database becomes enormous.

Please, share you thoughts about this strategy and especially about foreign keys. For now we need at least max_locks_per_transaction limited to 512, otherwise pg_dump is failed with
`ERROR: out of shared memory HINT: You might need to increase max_locks_per_transaction. pg_dump: error: query was: LOCK TABLE`. Besides locking nightmare, as far as I known, Postgres has limits for relations per database(the total number is huge but not unlimited). Do I need to make foreign keys for each partition table or just a part(certain rows) of a partitionED(general) table will be locked on insert, delete or update because all partitions are just "storages" but not a real relational entites?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

15K tables == Gag!

Partitioning is not likely to be any better than multiple tables.

Neither provides any performance benefits except in rare cases.

Let's investigate the future need for sharding.  That, alone, may justify the existence of `journal_nnn`.  In this, some journals would be on one machine, some on another machine, etc.  Are all journals in active use?  Or are most of them "old" and not really used?

The `PRIMARY KEY` can be a composite of two (or more) columns.

`AUTO_INCREMENT` has some advantages over manually creating "serial numbers".  (However, the Question does not have enough details for me to elaborate.)

`FOREIGN KEYs` are two things: an implied `INDEX` (good for performance) and a constraint (good for integrity).  In a well-debugged app, the integrity checks are unnecessary overhead.  They *must* be abandoned in partitioning and probably in sharding.

Comment: With 200000 partitions, query planning will become intolerably slow, and each SQL statement will need very many locks and open files. This won't work well.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. So the solution you recommend 1) just merge tables with same structure into one, distinguish by old seq_id and new journal_id(extracted from table name) 2) partitioning makes sense for future sharding but ranges has to be wider (by year? for example)

Comment: By year?  Does this imply that most of the activity is in just one table/partition/shard?

Comment: I need to double check the data "granulation" to choose a proper range. I gave an example just to found out how reasonably big partition has to be to keep performance.

Answer (score 1):

Having 50000 tables starts to get painful, and it makes no sense with a small database like this. The same holds for partitioning – after all, partitions are tables with a side job.

I would define only one table per object type.

About the auto-generated primary key numbers: make a combined primary key that consists of the old primary key and the table number (`journal_id`). For new entries, use a sequence that is initialized higher than the existing maximum of all tables.

Comment: But how about bigserial fields? The idea is keep creating(but manually) sequences and call for nextval on inserts.

Comment: Why not `bigserial` (or, even better, an identity column)?

Comment: Because each journal table has it's own bigserial and this auto incremented values are using elsewhere :( so, I can't just make a new global one sequence for all merged tables. I guess you probably asking because thousands sequences is not good approach as well because of performance?

Comment: Ah, I see. I have added an idea to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use partitioning for such a small database? Your average table is less then 2MB in size, that's really really small.

Get rid of the partitioning and your problems are gone.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm going to do first of all - merge tables with the same structure and just leaving(for a future) a possibility to shard partions if and only they will big enough. I have just one open question for now which I'm not sure about. What should I better do with serial fields? the plan was to put(on merging) values in a bigint field, but keep creating sequences for each journal/log and call nextval manually on inserts depends on journal_id. The primary key in this case is composite: journal_id(extracted from table name) and seq_id(independent sequence for each journal_id).

Comment: I would have just one bigserial for each table, but only if I need a serial. I would also try to make it as simple as possible, create one table that could serve for all (or at least for most) types of journals/logs. Your setup sounds like the opposite, as complex as possible. When that's the case, maintenance becomes difficult, database becomes slow, etc. Aim for simplicity.

Comment: Thank you @Frank. This is exactly what I'm trying to achieve - redesign this legacy and make it simple as it possible, but all journals have already their serials and I can't just make a new and one sequence in new(merged) table.